# How to share posts if no one is interested and not enough rep for bounties?

Tags: support, bounty, share

So I have [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1617910/understanding-the-raw-data-on-ms-powerpoint-presentations) still lying around with only a single comment showing some special keys, but I'm hoping for an answer that very well suits the aspect of the question.

It has been there for nearly a month and I want to somehow get it more attention. I thought of using bounties but I don't have enough rep. So what about sharing? If I would post it somewhere, maybe Twitter, I don't think anyone would even be interested, and people I message don't even have an interest in computer hardware/software.

So what's the next best option to get it more attention?

Comment: It might help if you included the "peculiar data" in the question. As it stands I don't think it can be answered.

Answer (score 2):

The [community bot](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community) apparently "pokes" random questions every hour so they can get more attention, but I looked at your question and I think that you are going to have more clarity like DavidPostill said in a comment to your original post.